# S3 Backup Memory Usage in Python

Tags: python, memory, upload, amazon-s3

I currently use WebFaction for my hosting with the basic package that gives us 80MB of RAM. This is more than adequate for our needs at the moment, apart from our backups. We do our own backups to S3 once a day.

The backup process is this: dump the database, tar.gz all the files into one backup named with the correct date of the backup, upload to S3 using the python library provided by Amazon.

Unfortunately, it appears (although I don't know this for certain) that either my code for reading the file or the S3 code is loading the entire file in to memory. As the file is approximately 320MB (for today's backup) it is using about 320MB just for the backup. This causes WebFaction to quit all our processes meaning the backup doesn't happen and our site goes down.

So this is the question: Is there any way to not load the whole file in to memory, or are there any other python S3 libraries that are much better with RAM usage. Ideally it needs to be about 60MB at the most! If this can't be done, how can I split the file and upload separate parts?

Thanks for your help.

This is the section of code (in my backup script) that caused the processes to be quit:

```
filedata = open(filename, 'rb').read()
content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]
if not content_type:
    content_type = 'text/plain'
print 'Uploading to S3...'
response = connection.put(BUCKET_NAME, 'daily/%s' % filename, S3.S3Object(filedata), {'x-amz-acl': 'public-read', 'Content-Type': content_type})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't read the whole file into your filedata variable. you could use a loop and then just read ~60 MB and submit them to amazon.

```
backup = open(filename, 'rb')
while True:
    part_of_file = backup.read(60000000) # not exactly 60 MB....
    response = connection.put() # submit part_of_file here to amazon
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will this put the file up in separate parts and da i have to change the filename each loop or will the data all be concatenated together on the Amazon end? Is there anything special I have to do in the connection.put() to make it do this?

Comment: this would submit each part of a file as one single file. I don't know the amazon api but maybe there is a way to concatenate all file parts to a single file on the amazon side.

under connection.put() you could increment a number inside the filename. (backup_20100317_part1, part2, part3...)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I know this is the way I want to do the backups, but I have a few questions about this method. Firstly, if I read(60000000) and there is not that much data left to read, what will happen? Also, can I just have this: 
x = file.read(60000000)
upload x
while x:
   x = file.read(60000000)
   upload x

The reason I ask is because it is difficult for me to test this script on my machine and I can't test it on the server as if it fails it could bring the sites down.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: you can find infos to read() here: 
http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#file-objects
read() should return "" if ther is no more data to read. if there is less than 60000.. in the file you get the rest.

I strongly suggest you to test it! why not submit some file of your computer to amazon just to check whether it works. (test also the restore!)


    backup = open(filename, 'rb')
    while True:
        part_of_file = backup.read(60000000) # not exactly 60 MB....
        if part_of_file == "":
            break # we have read all
        else:
            #submit this part to amazon

Comment: Ok. I have the script backing up in parts perfectly. I did a dry run on my computer with no issues. However I am having difficulty re-combining the files.

My current process is this:
open new file for writing,
open parts 1, 2, n...,
backup.write(part1.read() + part2.read()...),
backup.close().

I can decompress the file, but when I un-tar the other files inside it, they are corrupt, the directories show as files.

I can confirm that the backups that were not split work perfectly so it is because of the splitting.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

It's a little late but I had to solve the same problem so here's my answer.

Short answer: in Python 2.6+ yes! This is because the `httplib` supports file-like objects as of v2.6. So all you need is...

```
fileobj = open(filename, 'rb')
content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]
if not content_type:
    content_type = 'text/plain'
print 'Uploading to S3...'
response = connection.put(BUCKET_NAME, 'daily/%s' % filename, S3.S3Object(fileobj), {'x-amz-acl': 'public-read', 'Content-Type': content_type})
```

Long answer...

The `S3.py` library uses python's `httplib` to do its `connection.put()` HTTP requests. You can see in the source that it just passes the `data` argument to the `httplib` connection.

From `S3.py`...

```
    def _make_request(self, method, bucket='', key='', query_args={}, headers={}, data='', metadata={}):

        ...

        if (is_secure):
            connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection(host)
        else:
            connection = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)

        final_headers = merge_meta(headers, metadata);
        # add auth header
        self._add_aws_auth_header(final_headers, method, bucket, key, query_args)

        connection.request(method, path, data, final_headers) # <-- IMPORTANT PART
        resp = connection.getresponse()
        if resp.status < 300 or resp.status >= 400:
            return resp
        # handle redirect
        location = resp.getheader('location')
        if not location:
            return resp
        ...
```

If we take a look at the [python httplib documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/httplib.html#httpconnection-objects) we can see that...

> `HTTPConnection.request(method, url[, body[, headers]])`
>
> This will send a request to the server using the HTTP request method method and the selector url. If the body argument is present, it should be a string of data to send after the headers are finished. Alternatively, it may be an open file object, in which case the contents of the file is sent; this file object should support fileno() and read() methods. The header Content-Length is automatically set to the correct value. The headers argument should be a mapping of extra HTTP headers to send with the request.
>
> *Changed in version 2.6: body can be a file object.*